# How to create a horizontal list with only one element shown at a time?

Tags: listview, scroll, swiftui, horizontallist

The best way to explain what I'm trying to achieve is to show the picture bellow.
[image]

I would like to implement the horizontal sliding card list with animation as seen above.
However I'm new to swiftUI and don't know where to even start so any help would be appreciated.
The list will only have 4 elements which will contain a list within them instead of the content. Similar to the image bellow.
[image]

Comment: Can you attach the code you have?

Comment: For this page I have not done anything yet, however I know how to make the search and segment control. Unless you mean the navigationView and TabBar? But those are implemented in other pages.

Comment: I think you need tabView not List

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a horizontal ScrollView. Here is a basic implementation.

For more see [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-using-scrollview)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let testData : [TestData] = [TestData(title: "Begginer"), TestData(title: "Medium"), TestData(title: "Hard")]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(testData, id: \.self) { data in
                    Text("\(data.title)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 600)
                        .background(Color(.darkGray))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TestData: Hashable {
    let title: String
}
```

[image: Basic horizontal ScrollView]

Comment: This is almost right, as you can see on the pictures there is always one card in the middle and the other ones are smaller. So that when the user swipes the next card will expand to the correct size and "snap" into view. I don't want it to be able to be between cards as you have shown in your answer.